# Error: [$injector:nomod] Module is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to upload a file with progress bar but getting 2 errors constantly, no matter what i do

1)module not defined and 2nd is [$injector:nomod] module not available.

http://jsfiddle.net/3m75wqt1/

this is my controller

PageController.js

```
var PageController = function ($scope, fileUpload ) {
angular.module('app', ['ngProgress'])
angular.module('app')
.controller('PageController', function ($scope) {
    //$scope.fileUpload = {};
});
PageController.$inject = ['$scope','ngProgress'];
```

};

I have done a lot of searching but unable to find the error.
any help would be appreciated... Thanks in advance

Comment: is it me or does it look strange that the module is inside of the controller?

Comment: @Nancy why do you have multiple modules?

Comment: @Nano i am new to angularjs .. Please guide me if i am wrong

Comment: This is an error:

    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngProgress']);

`'ngProgress'` should be used, not `ngProgress`. Btw you are linking gruntfile.js and ngprogress.js as the github pages, they are not going to work

Comment: @jai i read it sumwhere that if v set a dependency in module then v have to define it again

Comment: @Nancy, I suggest you to go through this tutorial once if you are new to angularjs(as you said.) : https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial , if you haven't already.

Comment: @thebelowcode these are my css and js files i have given the online links

Comment: Nancy, module in angular is just container for services, constrollers etc. In your fiddle you create empty module and use it, but when you try use it in derective and service - angular try found service with name `ngProgress` but you don't have it.

Comment: @Nancy, i udapte your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3m75wqt1/11/) your error does not reproduced

Comment: thanks @nano,@grundy but I am still getting those errors even after updating my code... rather $injector:unpr has also started coming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First at all the module method shoud not be called inside of a controller, so this:

```
var PageController = function ($scope, fileUpload) {
    angular.module('app', ['ngProgress'])
    angular.module('app')
        .controller('PageController', function ($scope) {//I will replace this with PageController 
            //$scope.fileUpload = {};
        });
    PageController.$inject = ['$scope', 'ngProgress'];
};
```

shoud look more like this:

```
var PageController = function ($scope, fileUpload) {
};
PageController.$inject = ['$scope', 'ngProgress'];
angular.module('app', ['ngProgress'])
angular.module('app').controller('PageController', PageController);
```

*i removed the function in your controller method and put your defined `PageController` at its place*

The second thing is that you dont need to call the module method twice, the first one is already returning the module, so the best approach shoud look like this:

```
var PageController = function ($scope, fileUpload) {
};
PageController.$inject = ['$scope', 'ngProgress'];
angular.module('app', ['ngProgress']).controller('PageController', PageController);
```

And i personaly like the array notation more than this, so my favorite would look like this, but that is up to you:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngProgress'//this is a module dependency (its also createt with angular.module)
]).controller('PageController', [
    '$scope',
    'fileUpload',//this is a dependency for the controller (probably a service)
    function ($scope, fileUpload) {
    }
]);
```